# WordPress (GoDaddy: Linux w/cPanel (Apache))_ My 2nd site is FUBAR__ subdomain multisite network installation

Tags: php, wordpress, indexing, subdomain, multisite

### Issue half resolved...

Full resolution by me alone is probably not possible but *I think* I know **what needs to be done**.

**Partially resolved part**
*After adding a new site in WordPress Admin and adding that site url to the cPanel "subdomains"; I:*

- Could ping subsite.domainName.xyz
- Could **not** access the *WP dashboard* of subSite. Received 404 error.
- Could **not** view the site (neither by clicking "Visit Site" nor typing url into a browser). *Received* a **403 Forbidden** error.

After a lot of troubleshooting, a stumbled upon an article discussing how to disable indexing in cPanel. Luckily, for unknown reasons, I read the short article in its entirety and knew this was a golden ticket!

- Spot checked many directories and sub-dirs to confirm **yup! every directory** made by initial default setup (GoDaddy/cPanel) had an index.php file in it.
- **None** of the directories created (indirectly) by me had an index.php file (created via cPanel subdomain tool and WP Admin console).
- I grabbed the index.php from my wp root :public_html (dir) and slapped that bad boy into my subsite.domainName.xyz sites folder and viola! I now receive a **500 err message**

#### Hot dog we cookin now!

- still can't view/"visit" the site [500 error message]
- still can't access the WP Dashboard (admin console thingy). [was 404 error, now 500 error]

I looked at 4-5 other index.php files. A lot read "silence is golden" but **others**. Well, the other ones are incredibly extensive/long and intimidating.

Here is *roughly* what needs to happen.

- Every directory (for subdomain site "subsite") needs to get a index.php file added (or simply turn off indexing for that entire subdirectory/subsite folder).
- Some of those index.php files need to be extensive.
- The dashboard, wordpress, and all content in the core/root WP install need to be *point to* or **referenced** by the index.php file so those files can be loaded there by displaying the Dashboard/webpages.

**Completely** or nearly copying all the root WP install files over to "subsite" directory would be the same as "install package on your new site" ***NO!*** Not doin it!

#### I simply need to figure out: *how/what do I write/configure* the index.php file to simply point upward so that everything that happens at domainName.xyz is replicated in subsite.domainName.xyz.

I am so close, if you have any information, please lay it on me!

Comment: simply set subsite.domainname.xyz as alias of domainname.xyz

Comment: That's it?!?! That will solve all the issues? So the reconfigurations and initial configs to create the second site (subsite) was all unnecessary? (definitely not wasted time/effort, I learned an insane amount of web "stuff" over the last week or two).
I'll run a backup and give your fix a shot!

Comment: Just to be clear/informative. The "subsite" is going to be more of a web app and the first site is just a really nice (but still) static website. Does this info change your action-plan-to-resolve-issue?

Comment: Your original request is **everything that happens at domainName.xyz is replicated in subsite.domainName.xyz**, but now you have said that the subsite is a web app but the first site is just a static website (so now they are different ? )

Answer (score 0):

> None of the directories created (indirectly) by me had an index.php
> file (created via cPanel subdomain tool and WP Admin console).

> I grabbed the index.php from my wp root :public_html (dir) and slapped
> that bad boy into my subsite.domainName.xyz sites folder and viola! I
> now receive a 500 err message

You shouldn't need to be copying your index.php file to the subdirectories if hoping to connect them as part of a multi-site network AFAIK. While you could map each domain (which it sounds like you're doing) or create path-based on-demand sites, [it's suggested](https://wordpress.org/support/article/before-you-create-a-network/#types-of-multisite-network) that you make the changes directly in the network settings in your Super Admin panel and otherwise [use of a plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search/multisite/) would surely ease your troubles.

However if you are to continue down this route, what you're looking to modify I don't believe are the index.php but the .htaccess files.

To be sure, check that you `wp-config.php` file has been set appropriately for sub-domain sites.

```
define( 'SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', true );
```

Then, how you modify the .htaccess files will vary but one example from the examples given [here](https://wordpress.org/support/article/multisite-network-administration/#htaccess-and-mod-rewrite) would look like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]
 
# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]
 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
# END WordPress
```

Then for the subdomains:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]
 
# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]
 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ wp/$1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
# END WordPress
```

In doing this, it should address your need to have

> all content in the core/root WP install need to be point to or
> referenced by the index.php file so those files can be loaded there by
> displaying the Dashboard/webpages.

Just for reference:

[htaccess for subdirectories](https://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess_for_subdirectories) - overview of other uses of the .htaccess file As a side note, a .htaccess file is a granular configuration file for the Apache web server software, used to set or alter the server’s configuration settings for the directory in which it is present, and/or its child directories. It should go without saying that it is a hidden file in Unix/Linux and viewing of hidden files need to be enabled if using the File Manager in Cpanel or otherwise the `-a` option set when using `ls -a`

[Changing File Permissions](https://wordpress.org/support/article/changing-file-permissions/) - It may be a matter of file permissions if the files were not made through Wordpress Network settings and would explain why you're getting a forbidden error.